# association.first returns nil in an RSpec feature spec using a FactoryGirl factory with a has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, associations, factory-bot

I have the following in a Rails 4 app:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :todo_list do
    after(:create) do |t|
      create_list(:item, 3, todo_list: t)
    end

    factory :public_todo_list do
      is_public true
    end
  end

  factory :item do
    sequence(:position) { |n| n }
    name "This is item ##{:position}?"
    todo_list
  end
end
```

I have the following in a feature spec:

```
feature "TodoLists" do
  let(:todo_list) { create(:public_todo_list) }

  scenario "Something that requires accessing the first item" do
    ...
    pending todo_list.items.first.name
    ...
  end
end
```

However, the test fails with the following:

```
Failure/Error: pending todo_list.items.first.name
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Being that `todo_list.items` is an `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Item` object, it seems that `first` should return the first `Item` record? I get `nil` instead. `todo_list.items.count` returns `3` and `test.log` shows all the records being created correctly. What am I missing?

Comment: Why `pending` todo_list.items.first.name?

Comment: @KirtiThorat, I just changed it to `pending` when I was trying to inspect some output. You can ignore the `pending`. Still get the `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass` error when calling this elsewhere.

Comment: Are you calling the `todo_list` object before the line with `todo_list.items.first.name`?

Comment: @backpackerhh, I'm not. Do you ask this because I'm using `let`? I tried it with `todo_list = create(:public_todo_list)` and then tried calling `todo_list` prior to this line and still get the `nil` value.

Comment: Have you tried reloading the `todo_list.items`?

Comment: What do you mean by reloading?

Comment: `todo_list.items.reload`

Comment: @backpackerhh, that worked! Hmm... So why is `reload` required? PS. If you write up an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reloading the association before accessing the first item:

```
todo_list.items.reload
```

I think the `reload` is needed because the `todo_list` object doesn't have any item when is created, and I suspect that RSpec caches this. The `items` are created after the creation of `todo_list` object.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the sub-factory syntax in quite some time, but do they inherit the callbacks from the parent factory? Try doing this with a trait instead, which seems to make more sense for what you're doing anyway.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :todo_list do
    after(:create) do |t|
      create_list(:item, 3, todo_list: t)
    end

    trait :public do
      is_public true
    end
  end

  factory :item do
    sequence(:position) { |n| n }
    name "This is item ##{:position}?"
    todo_list
  end
end
```

and then:

```
feature "TodoLists" do
  let(:todo_list) { create(:todo_list, :public) }

  scenario "Something that requires accessing the first item" do
    ...
    pending todo_list.items.first.name
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Still getting the same error :( Although, thanks for the mention about traits. Those are better in this situation.